# Given a line and a point in 3D, how to find the closest point on the line?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have a point given by $P = (P_x, P_y, P_z)$, and a line give by the two points $Q = (Q_x, Q_y, Q_z)$ and $R = (R_x, R_y, R_z)$. I'd like to know a general formula to figure out the closest point to $P$ that resides on the line $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$. I know that this involves finding a perpendicular line to $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$, but I don't know where to go from there.

Edit: Based on Emilio's answer, I came up with this formula to derive the point;
$$\hat{t}=\frac{(R-Q)\cdot(Q-P)}{(R-Q)\cdot(R-Q)}$$
Where $\hat{t}$ is a scalar magnitude that can be used in the following formula.

$$G=Q-\hat{t}(R-Q)$$

Where $G$ is the point residing on the line $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$ closest to point  $P$.

Comment: In your second equation, I think you want Q - t(R - Q).

Comment: @Bob yes thank you! Will edit the formula to reflect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

find the plane orthogonal to the given line and passing thorough the point $P$.
The intersection of this plane with the line is the searched point.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That makes quite a bit of sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:
1.Take any general point on the given line in terms of any parameter.
Let it be S(x,y,z).
(Basically write the equation in cartesian form and then take x,y,z in the form of any parameter (let it be 'l'))

2.Now you have the vector PS.

3.As PS is perpendicular to the given line, it must be perpendicular to the direction ratios of the vector that the given line is parallel to.

4.Take the dot product of vector PS with the direction ratios of the given line and equate it to 0.(Dot product of non-zero perpendicular vectors is 0).

5.Now you have the parameter 'l' in terms of which you wrote the co-ordinates of S.

6.You now have the co-ordinates of S, so simply use distance formula to find the reqd. distance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given in the edit to the original question is sufficient if one **only** needs to find a point $G$ on the line $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$ where $G$ **doesn't** need to be *between* $Q$ and $R$.

That is to say, the formulæ given in the original answer:

$$
\hat{t}=\frac{(R-Q)\cdot(Q-P)}{(R-Q)\cdot(R-Q)}
$$

$$
G=Q-\hat{t}(R-Q)
$$

are sufficient for finding $G$ as a point on the *infinitely long line* that is normal with $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$.

However, if one needs (as I do) to find a point **between** $Q$ and $R$ that is closest to $P$, some additional steps are needed to *clamp* $G$ to be on the line bounded by $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$:

1. $D = R - Q$ gives us the *direction* of $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$
2. $F = G - Q$ tells us how far away $G$ is from the start of $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$, preserving whether it is before, in between or after $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$.
3. We define a special form of *Hadamard division* ($\odot$) that divides vectors element-wise, except where division by zero is special-cased to yield zero rather than be undefined.

   We calculate $H = F \odot D$
4. $H$ now gives the proportional distance along $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$ that $G$ lies in each axis. For a line that isn't normal with any of the axes, these elements will all be equal and we can use any of them for the distance.

   But in general, we have to account for the possibility that the line is normal with any of the axes, which would give zero elements for those axes in $H$.
5. Pick $z$ to be any non-zero element in $H$, if there are any, else zero (*you could also calculate $z$ as the average of all non-zero elements if floating point precision is a concern*)
6. Finally, we can calculate *normalised* position $\tilde{G}$ as follows:

$$
\tilde{G} =
\begin{cases}
Q & \text{if $z \lt 0$} \\
R & \text{if $z \gt 1$} \\
G & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: As some users might be able to tell, I am a programmer with an interest in mathematics, not a mathematician. Suggestions for improvements to my answer, including anything that could've been optimised to take fewer steps, are welcome!